# Excel's IRR function seemingly differs from actual math

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac, microsoft-excel-2016, office365

I am currently developing a web application that will have to do IRR calculations and as such need to develop a math formula for it.

Never the less, after messing around with online formula's. I developed this math formula which is a slight derivative of the original:

> d = 1 / period
>
> IRR = (FPV / PV)ᵈ
>
> ANNUALIZED = (IRR¹² - 1) * 100

Example of output:

> d = 1/2
>
> IRR = (99,821.77 / 78,062.85)¹/²
>
> IRR = 1.130812
>
> ANNUALIZED = (1.130812¹² - 1) * 100
>
> Final Number = 337.20% (Rounded)

However, when you use the in-built Excel IRR function with this formula, you get a very slightly different answer (second row not real formula, just what values are being pulled into it):

```
=(IRR(($N$9,O10), 0.001)+1)^12-1

=(IRR((78062.85,99821.77), 0.001)+1)^12-1
```

> Excel Final Number: 337.90%

Interestingly, the larger the period is I calculate, the more my number begins to be closer to the excel number.

I have thus far been unable to determine what excel is doing differently to arrive at this slightly different number.

Comment: You are rounding your numbers to 6 decimals, Excel will use 15 significant digits, so in this case 14 decimals.

Comment: It's not that, I double checked with 14 digits, its the number that Excel comes up with which is '1.13096160691355' before annualizing it. While mine comes up with '1.13081206042202'.

Comment: Your IRR formula does not work as one of the numbers must be negative.  so it is hard to verify your outcome.